# Instantiate a PGPPrivateKey object with an arbitrary private key block

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

Given a PGP public key block like below, how does one instantiate a BouncyCastle PGPPrivateKey object using the key?

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK----
mQIlNBGBBZ2nr0M7Dlw9s7u8MlbZvkPviVQF4lNzQ5tSmGNT0QV/QuC8a/gQ
...
...
...
Bhn0TfXYINgO0fIj4CjIduDn1aoUcQ5gF2XuA==
=3U0p
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

I've found numerous examples of how to obtain a PGPPrivateKey from a PGPSecretKeyRing, but unfortunately I am starting from private keys in he format above. I haven't been able to find  a way to either instantiate a PGPPrivateKey using that data, or place the data into a PGPSecretKeyRing for easy extraction.

A means of going from the PRIVATE KEY BLOCK format to a Java representation don't appear to be supported out of the box by BouncyCastle, but I also don't know where to begin going about transforming them into a format that's usable. I've tried many permutations of the below and similar versions using PGPObjectFactory, but haven't been able to find a way to hand off the private key block in a format that the PGP library knows how to consume.

```
privateKeyInputStream = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(privateKeyBytes));
    PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSecretKeyRingCollection =
            new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(privateKeyInputStream, new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator() );
    Iterator keyRingIterator = pgpSecretKeyRingCollection.getKeyRings();
    while(keyRingIterator.hasNext()) {
        String className = keyRingIterator.next().getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println("keyRingIterator object : " + className); // never called
    }
```

How can a private key provided by a PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK be used to decrypt a file in Java code?

Comment: [That file format standardly _is_](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-11.2) (or should be) what Bouncy calls a SecretKeyRingCollection which is one or more SecretKeyRing's **EXCEPT IT'S MISSING THE EMPTY LINE between the 'BEGIN' line and the base64**. Is that only a posting artifact or is the real file like that? If the real file has the empty line your posted code should work. If not and you can recreate with a test key(group) whose security doesn't matter, post it unredacted for us to investigate. I'm assuming you mangled even the non-dotted base64 because it's not valid either.

Comment: You're correct, I mangled the contents a bit. The missing line was not a pasting artifact, but I added a new line into a test file and now BouncyCastle is able to parse the content and items are in the SecretKeyRing. I'm now in a place where I should be able to extract a PGPPrivateKey. Thanks!